# Django - add text beetween modelform fields

Tags: django, django-forms

How can I add some html text beetween form fields? This is my forms.py:

```
class SiteAddFormFull(forms.ModelForm):

    url = forms.URLField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly': 'readonly'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'description', 'keywords', 'group', 'category',
              'subcategory', 'category1', 'subcategory1', 'email')

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        subcategory = cleaned_data['subcategory']
        subcategory1 = cleaned_data['subcategory1']
        if subcategory1 and (subcategory == subcategory1):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Subcategories can't be the same.")
```

Part of my html file:

```
<form method="post" action="" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form_extended layout='horizontal'%}
    {% bootstrap_button "Zatwierdź" size='large' button_type="submit" button_class="btn-primary" %}
</form>
```

I would like to add description after 'group' field. Something like:

- You can add site to 2 categories
- You can add site to 2 subcategories

Just normal html text. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to add custom HTML tags then do this:

```
class Meta:
    model = Site
    fields = ('url', 'name', 'description', 'keywords', 'group', 'category', 'subcategory', 'category1', 'subcategory1', 'email')
    help_texts = {
        'field_name': '<span class="my-class">Some useful help text.</span>',
    }
```

More on this [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields)

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `help_text` attribute to your model's group field:

```
class Site(models.Model):
    group = models.<FieldType>(..., help_text="You can add site to 2 categories")
```

Comment: Is it possible to format (add html tags) to help_text?

Comment: It could be possible if you wrap them in `mark_safe()`. I haven't tried that though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I made it that way:

```
group = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=(('podstawowy', 'podstawowy'),
                                                 ('premium', 'premium')), default='podstawowy',
                         help_text="<div id='group'><ul><li>You can add site to 2 <b>categories</b></li></ul></div>")
```

There is additional problem here. If there will be 3,4,5 lines of html code, here there will be a mess in my code. How should I write it? Is it possible to include some html text from external file. Maybe another solution?

Comment: From my point of view, if its gonna be just 3 or 4 or 5 lines of code and not going to be reused elsewhere, then there is no need to write them in a separate module. Just write them inside the `help_text` as you do.